# AWS Elastic Beanstalk error - ImportError: No module named flask.ext.sqlalchemy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, flask-sqlalchemy

I deployed my flask application into aws beanstalk and ran into an import error:

```
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.sqlalchemy
```

In my application.py file, I have this statement

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

and it runs fine on my machine but does not work in aws elastic beanstalk.

Anyone ran into a similar issue?

Comment: The Flask-SQLAlchemy extension is now located at `flask_sqlalchemy`. See [the documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure you have included a requirements.txt file in root directory of your project.

The file should include any pip package that needs to be installed

```
Flask-SQLAlchemy=1.0
```

http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#requirements-files

Comment: link appears broken. Is this link the same thing? http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#requirements-files

Comment: Yes, looks like they update there docs.  I will update above.  Thanks

Comment: Run `sudo pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0` to get this puppy from the cmdline.